# Applescript/Photoshop: Create new layer with image

Tags: macos, applescript, photoshop

How can I create a new layer in a document with an image in that layer? I am using Pohotoshop CS5 and AppleScript.
I know how to make a new layer like this:

```
    set newLayer to make art layer with properties {name:"LayerA"}
```

Just don't know how to put an image in it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it copied straight from a file, that's more complicated, and requires to open up a different app (Preview) and copy it from Preview. This may help:

```
    set this_picture to choose file
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open this_picture
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        keystroke "a" using command down
        keystroke "c" using command down
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Preview" to quit
```

That asks for an image, opens Preview, selects all of the image, copies it, and then quits.

To then paste it into Photoshop:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
        activate
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Adobe Photoshop CS5"
            set newLayer to make art layer with properties {name:"LayerA"}
            keystroke "v" using command down
        end tell
    end tell
```

And that's basically it! Hope that helped in some way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way I can copy a layer in between documents opened within photoshop? thanks again.

Comment: The second part of your code don't work with Photoshop 2022 ! 
Can you fix it please?